# Why is the Graph Data Science Library Plug In preventing me from starting a database

Tags: jupyter-notebook, neo4j

I'm trying to run a database with the apoc and gds plugins. However, if I have the gds plugin installed attemtping to start the database responds in the following error: "DBMS failed to restart: DBMS process terminated, see logs".
Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with reading errors in the logs. Can anyone tell me what's happening in this?

```
[2023-11-11 21:46:50.496] [info]  Check if neo4j is available on { host: '127.0.0.1', path: '/', port: 7687 }
[2023-11-11 21:46:50.497] [info]  Check if neo4j is available on { host: '127.0.0.1', path: '/', port: 7474 }
[2023-11-11 21:46:50.498] [info]  Neo4j @ 7687 is down. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7687
[2023-11-11 21:46:50.499] [info]  Neo4j @ 7474 is down. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7474
[2023-11-11 21:46:51.509] [info]  Retrieved status for DBMS[database-d66031cf-5040-434c-ae01-65887d023f17]: false
[2023-11-11 21:47:12.339] [info]  Online check request: https://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-desktop/win/latest.yml
[2023-11-11 21:47:12.445] [info]  Online check response: 200 version: 1.5.9
```

Comment: It looks like the Neo4j server failed to start after you attempted to install the GDS plugin. Check that you have followed all the instructions for [installing the plugin](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/installation/), and also check [the logs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/5/monitoring/logging/#_log_files) on the DB server itself for any issues.